# Signin with facebook

Tags: laravel

In my code I check the account status from users table if it is 1 then shows the detail of user. By default the value of account status is 1. When i run the code that condition doesn't work. Here is my code. Please Help. Thanks in advance.

```
public function signInFacebook(SignInFacebookUser $request)
{
    if($profile_picture = $request->hasFile('profile_picture')) {
        $profile_picture = time().'.'.$request->profile_picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->profile_picture->move(public_path('Storage/ProfileImages'), $profile_picture);
        $profile_picture = 'Storage/ProfileImages/'.$profile_picture;
    } else {
        $profile_picture = NULL;
    }

    try {
        $user = User::updateOrCreate([
            'facebook_id' => $request->input('facebook_id'),
        ],
        [
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'surname' => $request->input('surname'),
            'date_of_birth' => $request->input('date_of_birth'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'city' => $request->input('city'),
            'university' => $request->input('university'),
            'profile_picture' => $profile_picture,
        ]);

    } catch (QueryException $e) {
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];          
        if($errorCode == 1062){
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Duplicate Entry']);
        }
    }

    $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

    if($user->account_status == 1) {
        $userDetail = $user->where('id', $user->id)->first();
        return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'user' => $userDetail], 200);
    } 
    else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'you are not active on app, contact to support team'], 200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the changing I done in my code and it works.

```
public function signInFacebook(SignInFacebookUser $request)
{
    if($profile_picture = $request->hasFile('profile_picture')) {
        $profile_picture = time().'.'.$request->profile_picture->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->profile_picture->move(public_path('Storage/ProfileImages'), $profile_picture);
        $profile_picture = 'Storage/ProfileImages/'.$profile_picture;
    } else {
        $profile_picture = NULL;
    }

    try {
        $user = User::updateOrCreate([
            'facebook_id' => $request->input('facebook_id'),
        ],
        [
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'surname' => $request->input('surname'),
            'date_of_birth' => $request->input('date_of_birth'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'city' => $request->input('city'),
            'university' => $request->input('university'),
            'profile_picture' => $profile_picture,
        ]);
    } catch (QueryException $e) {
            $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];          
        if($errorCode == 1062){
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Duplicate Entry']);
        }
    }

    if(!$user) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'failed to signin with facebook'], 200);
    }

    $userDetail = $user->where('id', $user->id)->first();

    if ($userDetail->account_status == 1) {
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
        return response()->json(['token' => $token, 'user' => $userDetail], 200);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'you are not active on app, contact to support team'], 200);
    }   
}
```